# nullpointererror + unable to bind sockets

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets

This works in the earlier version of my app, which is basically the exact same code. The only difference is the current app uses a higher build tools and sdk compiled version, would that cause the code to error? Also the app extends FragmentActivity instead of Activity now.

One of the errors is a null pointer exception, which from logcat is due to the ServerSocket (ss) being null.

The other error is libcore.io.ErrnoException: bind failed: EADDRINUSE (Address already in use) at the line 8 in the snippet

I have tried implementing  ss.setReuseAddress(true), however it doesn't work due to an unresolved symbol issue?

Any idea or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

```
class CommsThread implements Runnable {
    private volatile boolean stopFlag = false;
    private ServerSocket ss ;
    private static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;
    public void run() {
        Socket s = null;
        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT); <-- bind error here
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG,"IO Error here"); <--- this is printed in log
      }

        try {
            s = ss.accept(); <----- nullpointer exception here
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

        while(stopFlag == false){
            try {
                out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream())), true);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                out.printf(String.valueOf(d.format(accel[0]))+"\t"+String.valueOf(d.format(accel[1]))+"\t"+String.valueOf(d.format(accel[2])) + "\tAccelerometer" + "\n");
                out.printf(String.valueOf(d.format(gyro[0]))+"\t"+String.valueOf(d.format(gyro[1]))+"\t"+String.valueOf(d.format(gyro[2]))+ "\tGyroscope" + "\n");
                out.printf(String.valueOf(d.format(magnet[0]))+"\t"+String.valueOf(d.format(magnet[1]))+"\t"+String.valueOf(d.format(magnet[2]))+"\tMagnetometer"+ "\n\n");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if( s==null)
            {
                stopComms();
            }
            */
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NPE is due to nothing but your own faulty code structure. The real issue is the bind exception, which means something else is listening at port 6000, possibly a prior instance of the same application. Fix that, or use another port.

Comment: I've made sure it's the only instance, and have also tried assigning a different port to no avail. Any other problems that could be causing it?

Also as I said the exact same snippet of code works for the other application. Why would the code structure issue a NPE for this code and not the other :/?

Comment: The NPE only happens when there is a failure to create the `ServerSocket`, and is due to your faulty program structure which continues to execute after the failure as though the failure didn't happen. There is no point in trying to accept from a socket that doesn't even exist. Code that depends on the success of code in a prior `try` block should be inside that `try` block. Don't write code like this. As for the actual failure, 'address already in use' means exactly what it says, and what I said.

Comment: Ah, thanks for explaining that. Will rewrite and see how it goes.
Guess this is as close as any to an answer.